# How do I use Apache Spark and lxml to parse, filter, and aggregate data?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I've created a generic XMLparser from [lxml](https://lxml.de/2.2/index.html) utilizing `etree.fromstring(x)`.  Now I have to parse an XML like the following:

```
 <row AcceptedAnswerId="88156" AnswerCount="6" Body="&lt;p&gt;I\'ve just played a game with my kids that basically boils down to: whoever rolls every number at least once on a 6-sided dice wins.&lt;/p&gt;&#10;&#10;&lt;p&gt;I won, eventually, and the others finished 1-2 turns later. Now I\'m wondering: what is the expectation of the length of the game?&lt;/p&gt;&#10;&#10;&lt;p&gt;I know that the expectation of the number of rolls till you hit a specific number is &#10;$\\sum_{n=1}^\\infty n\\frac{1}{6}(\\frac{5}{6})^{n-1}=6$.&lt;/p&gt;&#10;&#10;&lt;p&gt;However, I have two questions:&lt;/p&gt;&#10;&#10;&lt;ol&gt;&#10;&lt;li&gt;How many times to you have to roll a six-sided dice until you get every number at least once? &lt;/li&gt;&#10;&lt;li&gt;Among four independent trials (i.e. with four players), what is the expectation of the &lt;em&gt;maximum&lt;/em&gt; number of rolls needed? [note: it\'s maximum, not minimum, because at their age, it\'s more about finishing than about getting there first for my kids]&lt;/li&gt;&#10;&lt;/ol&gt;&#10;&#10;&lt;p&gt;I can simulate the result, but I wonder how I would go about calculating it analytically.&lt;/p&gt;&#10;&#10;&lt;hr&gt;&#10;&#10;&lt;p&gt;Here\'s a Monte Carlo simulation in Matlab&lt;/p&gt;&#10;&#10;&lt;pre&gt;&lt;code&gt;mx=zeros(1000000,1);&#10;for i=1:1000000,&#10;   %# assume it\'s never going to take us &amp;gt;100 rolls&#10;   r=randi(6,100,1);&#10;   %# since R2013a, unique returns the first occurrence&#10;   %# for earlier versions, take the minimum of x&#10;   %# and subtract it from the total array length&#10;   [~,x]=unique(r); &#10;   mx(i,1)=max(x);&#10;end&#10;&#10;%# make sure we haven\'t violated an assumption&#10;assert(~any(mx==100))&#10;&#10;%# find the expected value for the coupon collector problem&#10;expectationForOneRun = mean(mx)&#10;&#10;%# find the expected number of rolls as a maximum of four independent players&#10;maxExpectationForFourRuns = mean( max( reshape( mx, 4, []), [], 1) )&#10;&#10;expectationForOneRun =&#10;   14.7014 (SEM 0.006)&#10;&#10;maxExpectationForFourRuns =&#10;   21.4815 (SEM 0.01)&#10;&lt;/code&gt;&lt;/pre&gt;&#10;" CommentCount="5" CreationDate="2013-01-24T02:04:12.570" FavoriteCount="9" Id="48396" LastActivityDate="2014-02-27T16:38:07.013" LastEditDate="2013-01-26T13:53:53.183" LastEditorUserId="198" OwnerUserId="198" PostTypeId="1" Score="23" Tags="&lt;probability&gt;&lt;dice&gt;" Title="How often do you have to roll a 6-sided dice to obtain every number at least once?" ViewCount="5585" />',
 '  <row AnswerCount="1" Body="&lt;p&gt;Suppose there are $6$ people in a population. During $2$ weeks $3$ people get the flu. Cases of the flu last $2$ days. Also people will get the flu only once during this period. What is the incidence density of the flu?&lt;/p&gt;&#10;&#10;&lt;p&gt;Would it be $\\frac{3}{84 \\text{person days}}$ since each person is observed for $14$ days?&lt;/p&gt;&#10;" CommentCount="4" CreationDate="2013-01-24T02:23:13.497" Id="48397" LastActivityDate="2013-04-24T16:58:18.773" OwnerUserId="20010" PostTypeId="1" Score="1" Tags="&lt;epidemiology&gt;" Title="Incidence density" ViewCount="288" />',
```

We'll suppose that my goal is to pull out the CommentCount values, and aggregate them.  As I'm doing this through PySpark, this is, of course, only a very small sample of the data.

I've attempted to use my parser jointly with `.filter()`, `reduceByKey`, but haven't had much success. Presumably my the lxml parser mentioned above returns a dictionary, though I haven't been able to confirm that's the case.

Can anyone explain the best way to aggregate the CommentCount values in the XML above?

*Note: Databricks cannot be installed on my system, any solution must not require this.*

Comment: That is one of the less efficient ways to work with xml and spark (your data resides in the jvm and needs to transfered to the python interpreter to use your code). What kind of object contains your xml snippet? Is it a dataframe? If so, please add the output of df.printSchema(). Does your requirement of a none databricks answer also include spark packages like [spark=xml](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml)?

Comment: @cronoik - The data is read in from the cloud as a mass of XML (no RDD or Dataframe yet. As I mentioend, I'm a bit unclear about what the parser returns, but surely it's not a DF yet.  The answer should only need to use `lxml` and Spark "native".  If I'm not mistaken, I believe `spark-xml` is part of Databricks, no? While I presume Databrick's spark-xml would make the process more efficient, unfortunately, I don't have the capability of installing it on the server I'm working with.

Comment: Correction: I am reading the XML into an RDD before parsing.

Comment: So....why the downvotes?  Apparently nobody understands that I been researching this for the last 15 hours with little progress...

Comment: you can handle this with builtin functions if each row is valid xml and on its own line, or can be converted into valid xml easily, for example trimming some irrelevant leading /trailing chars as shown in your current example.

Comment: @jxc - that's good to know.  Under those assumptions, you mentioned, how would you do that? This is the problem I've not been able to solve...

Comment: @alofgran, I would read the file into DataFrame in line mode (for example, df = spark.read.text(....)) and use `xpath` to get the attribute values. if this looks doable from your end, I can add  an answer.

Comment: @jxc the concept does sound feasible to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can try is the Spark SQL **[xpath](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#xpath)** related builtin functions, but only if the xmls are all valid XML(or can be easily converted into valid XMLs) and on their own line.

```
# read file in line mode, we get one column with column_name = 'value'
df = spark.read.text('....')
```

For example, with the current sample XMLs, we can trim the leading and trailing commas, single-quotes and spaces, take the XPATH `row//@CommentCount` which is the value of CommentCount attribute under the row tag, this will get an array column of matched attribute values:

```
df.selectExpr('''xpath(trim(both ",' " from value), "row//@CommentCount") as CommentCount''').show()   
+------------+
|CommentCount|
+------------+
|         [5]|
|         [4]|
+------------+
```

You can then take the sum on the first element of each array:

```
df.selectExpr('''
    sum(xpath(trim(both ",' " from value), "row//@CommentCount")[0]) as sum_CommentCount
''').show()
+----------------+
|sum_CommentCount|
+----------------+
|             9.0|
+----------------+
```

Problem with this method is that it's very fragile and any invalid XML will fail the whole process and I don't find any fix for this as of now.

Another way is to use API function: [regex_extract](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract), which can be practical since the texts you want to retrieve is simple (i.e. no embedded tags or quotes etc).

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_extract

df.select(regexp_extract('value', r'\bCommentCount="(\d+)"', 1).astype('int').alias('CommentCount')).show()                                                                                                   
+------------+
|CommentCount|
+------------+
|           5|
|           4|
+------------+
```

you can then take the sum on this integer column. Just my 2 cents.